# What did Martha mean in John 11:24 by the term "resurrection"?

Tags: john, prophecy, resurrection

-- John 11:24 (ASV)

> Martha saith unto him, I know that he shall rise again in the resurrection at the last day.

Comment: Could you clarify what the differences between the two types of resurrection are?

Comment: Could you define the two resurrections mentioned? It's almost certain she is harkening back to Job 19:25-27.

Comment: Edited to format quotes appropriately. Because you use a variety of translations it is really important to identify each.

Comment: @ONicolas Could you please save everybody some time and just post "The Infallible JW Answer" to your "questions" rather than engaging in pretense? Your "question" does not contain a question!! Move to close.

Comment: @ONicolas A strange interpretation, to say it mildly: fear of being cast to "gehenna" after death most clearly indicates that even after bodily death an unrepenting sinner remains conscious of his/her sins and it is painful, "fire of gehenna" being commonly interpreted as a metaphor of pangs of conscience. By the same token, a righteous man is also conscious of divine presence in him/her after his bodily death. To say that God only grants a privilege of bliss to just 144 000 souls (which is a symbolic number of course) through the entire human history, is a naivety, again to put it mildly.

Comment: In rereading, this is not a question. It is titled as one, but the content is just sermonizing.

Comment: Mark. Earthly resurrection  John 5:28,29. Acts 24:15. Revelation 20:13,14.

Comment: Heavenly resurrection  Luke 12:32 . Revelation 20:4,6  those having part in the first resurrection.

Comment: Most of this belongs in an answer, not in the question. You need to cut 90% of it out.

Comment: curiousdannii :comment noted , hope it is an on topic question.

Answer (score 1):

One can only speculate what a person has in mind unless they say it. However, I would note the following:

- the OT does not contain a general resurrection (of all people)
- the Jews of the first century were divided on the matter with the Pharisees being the prominent supporters of a general resurrection and the Sadducees of no resurrection
- in the OT we see reference to both a national resurrection ("the valley of dry bones") and a heavenly resurrection ("shine as the stars in the sky")

However, Jesus raising Lazarus out of sleep in the context seems to suggest that it was somewhat of a paradigm of the resurrection in view with no mention of a heavenly resurrection.

Again, what she had in mind we can only speculate but I think she was thinking of a physical, earthly resurrection.

Comment: "Jesus raising Lazarus out of sleep", I guess in this phrase the "sleep" should be put in quotation marks, for it was not a literal sleep, a lethargic sleep so to say, but it was a four day laying of a dead corpse in a warm tomb so that it started already the process of decomposition as to emit horrible stench. Thus, it was literally a resurrection of Lazarus from actual death, a new creation of his decomposed body.

Comment: Possibly relevant to what she was thinking: Dan 12:2"Many of those who sleep in the dust of the ground will awake, these to everlasting life, but the others to disgrace and everlasting contempt. 3"Those who have insight will shine brightly like the brightness of the expanse of heaven, and those who lead the many to righteousness, like the stars forever and ever

Comment: Yes, absolutely relevant and enlightening reference; and again, in Dan. 12:2  as well as in the John 11:11 the "sleep" and "waking" are metaphors for actual death of body, as to soul, soul does not sleep after a bodily death, but according to mainstream Christian traditions (Catholic, Orthodox, majority of Protestant as well as Coptic, Armenian and Nestorian) keeps living and even with a greater bliss and intensity of communication with God (Phil. 1:23), so as to be able also to intercede for the living (the institution of saints in all the mentioned traditions).

Comment: One of the features of John 11 is that it spills a lot of ink to show that Jesus was surrounded by unbelief. For example, "If he's sleeping that's a good thing" and "We know that one day..." or "Let's go and die with him". So what she was thinking may or may not be correct.

Comment: I'd rather say fear than unbelief, but perhaps you are right in the sense that their fear came from the unbelief; but the immediate disposition is that of fear that Jews were searching for killing Jesus just a short time before and to go to Bethlehem at that time, meant sure risk of His and his disciples lives. Even Thomas' "Let's go and die with him" shows rather his indignation and fear, than his courage, for by those angry words he gave vent to his resentment against Jesus, obliquely attacking His stubbornness with regard of going by all means to Bethlehem for seeing and "waking" Lazarus.

Answer (score 0):

The type of question put is referred to in logic a "complex question fallacy" that means that a question includes in itself a hidden information, which itself may be contentious, but if a listener does not pay attention to it, then in his answer he will be trapped to comply with this information unwillingly, as for instance, when one asks you: "Why it is the KIA the best car brand in the world?" it implies a hidden information that the KIA is the best car brand, but you may not at all agree with it.

Thus, the present theological question implies that there are two resurrections - heavenly and earthly. BUT THIS DISTINCTION CAN NOT BE CORRECT AT ALL! The correct way to put question would be: "Are there two resurrections in Bible?".

For example, mainstream Christian confessions - Catholic, Orthodox, majority of Protestant - do not speak about two resurrections but maintain that human soul does not die with its body and that there is even (in Catholicism and Orthodoxy) a continuation of prayful communication with the deceased souls: for instance, saints' intercession can be addressed on a casual way, that is to say, there is a strong conviction and faith that the souls of the deceased saints live more fully in God and have even a greater intensity of communion with the Trinity so as to help their struggling brothers and sisters who still live on earth. St. Paul even groans with a desire of death which for him is a way of even a greater union into the life of Christ (Phil. 1:23); and he also speaks about the " "outer man" (flesh) decaying, while the inner man (soul) being renovated and growing in Christ (2 For. 4:16); Now, if one can speak about "spiritual resurrection", this is exactly the case: that is to say, when a person dies and is crucified for sins and the worldly lusts and resurrects in life of Christ's commandments (Gal. 2:20), in Christ's power that works in his heart with his free co-action or συνεργεία, and this is possible and even proscriptive for Christians even in their historical life. Thus, "spiritual resurrection" is such a term can be used, can denote a commitment of a Christian to transfigure his/her life, repent fully of sins and follow Christ, open his/her heart to salvific mighty activity of Christ (Col. 1:29).

However, to assert an existence of some other "spiritual resurrection", that is to say, a resurrection of some privileged guys (144 000 in number) in a bodiless fashion, as some privileged spirits who will soar like angels while the rest of the mankind will be in an unconscious condition until the final bodily resurrection is a mythology and old wives' tales to use St. Paul's expression (1 Tim. 4:7).

However, there is also a bodily resurrection of all, even the saints, who will be united again to their human bodies that will have a feature of incorruptibility; as Jesus' soul did survive (if one can be permitted saying this word) his body and did reunite with the same body and resurrected after three days.

This will happen with everybody in the general resurrection in the eschatological End of the Days. Thus, in Catholic and Orthodox theology and religious practice, when you stand in front of a tomb containing body of a saint, say St. Columba of Iona, and you ask for his intercession to God, you understand that St. Columba's soul stands prayfully before God and that his body which now lay in front of you, will be resurrected and reunited with his soul in the last day, for this perishable body will also be wrapped in imperishability through divine grace, for even their perishable will be wrapped in imperishable (1 Cor. 15: 54), and thus death will be completely conquered.

In the mainstream Christian traditions souls of the deceased live even more fully than in their short sojourn on earth and there is a full justification and sense to pray with love on their behalf, that God may alleviate and forgive their sins, and also address to them (to the saints), ask for their intercession, that they may be our helpers before God in our earthly struggles and calamities.

Thus, Martha must have spoken about the Final bodily Resurrection of all, and not a "spiritual resurrection", if this term implies the abovementioned spiritual renovation (death for sins and living for Christ).